# Tic tac toe game python glitch

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python, and I'm learning to code using udemy. I found this game and I'm trying to make it smart so it doesn't let me win easily but when I do that the game becomes glitchy, it works perfectly fine the first two rounds but then the machine doesn't want to click or play! I know this is  simple but I'm new so I hope you may help me. This is the code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import randint

ActivePlayer=1
p1=[] #what player one selected
p2=[] #what player two selected
root=Tk()
root.title("X/O:Player 1")
style=ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("classic")
style.configure("TButton", background='#427949')
style.map("Info.TButton", background=[('disabled', '#6d1b1b')])

bu1=ttk.Button(root,text='')
bu1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='snew',ipadx=40,ipady=40)
bu1.config(command=lambda: ButtonClick(1))

bu2=ttk.Button(root,text='')
bu2.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='snew',ipadx=40,ipady=40)
bu2.config(command=lambda: ButtonClick(2))
bu3=ttk.Button(root,text='')
bu3.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='snew',ipadx=40,ipady=40)
bu3.config(command=lambda: ButtonClick(3))

bu4=ttk.Button(root,text='')
bu4.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='snew',ipadx=40,ipady=40)
bu4.config(command=lambda: ButtonClick(4))

bu5=ttk.Button(root,text='')
bu5.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='snew',ipadx=40,ipady=40)
bu5.config(command=lambda: ButtonClick(5))

bu6=ttk.Button(root,text='')
bu6.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='snew',ipadx=40,ipady=40)
bu6.config(command=lambda: ButtonClick(6))

bu7=ttk.Button(root,text='')
bu7.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky='snew',ipadx=40,ipady=40)
bu7.config(command=lambda: ButtonClick(7))

bu8=ttk.Button(root,text='')
bu8.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='snew',ipadx=40,ipady=40)
bu8.config(command=lambda: ButtonClick(8))

bu9=ttk.Button(root,text='')
bu9.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky='snew',ipadx=40,ipady=40)
bu9.config(command=lambda: ButtonClick(9))

def ButtonClick(id):
    global ActivePlayer
    global p1
    global p2
    if(ActivePlayer==1):
        SetLayout(id,"X")
        p1.append(id)
        root.title("X/O:Player 2")
        ActivePlayer=2
        print("P1:{}".format(p1))
        AutoPlay()
    elif(ActivePlayer==2):
        SetLayout(id,"O")
        p2.append(id)
        root.title("X/O:Player 1")
        ActivePlayer=1
        print("P2:{}".format(p2))
    CheckWinner()
def SetLayout(id,PlayerSymbol):
    if id==1:
        bu1.config(text=PlayerSymbol)
        bu1.state(['disabled'])
        bu1.configure(style='Info.TButton')
    elif id==2:
        bu2.config(text=PlayerSymbol)
        bu2.state(['disabled'])
        bu2.configure(style='Info.TButton')
    elif id==3:
        bu3.config(text=PlayerSymbol)
        bu3.state(['disabled'])
        bu3.configure(style='Info.TButton')
    elif id==4:
        bu4.config(text=PlayerSymbol)
        bu4.state(['disabled'])
        bu4.configure(style='Info.TButton')
    elif id == 5:
        bu5.config(text=PlayerSymbol)
        bu5.state(['disabled'])
        bu5.configure(style='Info.TButton')
    elif id == 6:
        bu6.config(text=PlayerSymbol)
        bu6.state(['disabled'])
        bu6.configure(style='Info.TButton')
    elif id == 7:
        bu7.config(text=PlayerSymbol)
        bu7.state(['disabled'])
        bu7.configure(style='Info.TButton')
    elif id == 8:
        bu8.config(text=PlayerSymbol)
        bu8.state(['disabled'])
        bu8.configure(style='Info.TButton')
    elif id == 9:
        bu9.config(text=PlayerSymbol)
        bu9.state(['disabled'])
        bu9.configure(style='Info.TButton')
def CheckWinner():
    Winner=-1
    if(1 in p1) and (2 in p1) and (3 in p1):
        Winner=1
    if(1 in p2) and (2 in p2) and (3 in p2):
        Winner=2
    if(4 in p1) and (5 in p1) and (6 in p1):
        Winner=1
    if(4 in p2) and (5 in p2) and (6 in p2):
        Winner=2
    if(7 in p1) and (8 in p1) and (9 in p1):
        Winner=1
    if(7 in p2) and (8 in p2) and (9 in p2):
        Winner=2
    if(1 in p1) and (4 in p1) and (7 in p1):
        Winner=1
    if(1 in p2) and (4 in p2) and (7 in p2):
        Winner=2
    if(2 in p1) and (5 in p1) and (8 in p1):
        Winner=1
    if(2 in p2) and (5 in p2) and (8 in p2):
        Winner=2
    if(3 in p1) and (6 in p1) and (9 in p1):
        Winner=1
    if(3 in p2) and (6 in p2) and (9 in p2):
        Winner=2
    if(3 in p1) and (5 in p1) and (7 in p1):
        Winner=1
    if(3 in p2) and (5 in p2) and (7 in p2):
        Winner=2
    if(1 in p1) and (5 in p1) and (9 in p1):
        Winner=1
    if(1 in p2) and (5 in p2) and (9 in p2):
        Winner=2
    if Winner==1:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Congrats",message="Player 1 is the Winner!!")
        exit()
    elif Winner==2:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Congrats",message="Player 2 is the Winner!!")
        exit()

def AutoPlay():
    global p1
    global p2
    EmptyCells=[]
    for cell in range(9):
        if (not((cell+1 in p1) or (cell+1 in p2))):
            EmptyCells.append(cell+1)
    RandIndex=randint(0,len(EmptyCells)-1)
    if (1 in p1) and (2 in p1) or (6 in p1) and (9 in p1) or (5 in p1) and (7 in p1):
        ButtonClick(3)
    elif (4 in p1) and (5 in p1) or (3 in p1) and (9 in p1):
        ButtonClick(6)
    elif (7 in p1) and (8 in p1) or (3 in p1) and (6 in p1) or (1 in p1) and (5 in p1):
        ButtonClick(9)
    elif (1 in p1) and (4 in p1) or (3 in p1) and (5 in p1) or (8 in p1) and (9 in p1):
        ButtonClick(7)
    elif (2 in p1) and (5 in p1) or (7 in p1) and (9 in p1):
        ButtonClick(8)
    elif (1 in p1) and (3 in p1) or (5 in p1) and (8 in p1):
        ButtonClick(2)
    elif (4 in p1) and (6 in p1) or (2 in p1) and (8 in p1) or (3 in p1) and (7 in p1) or (1 in p1) and (9 in p1):
        ButtonClick(5)
    elif (1 in p1) and (7 in p1) or (5 in p1) and (6 in p1):
        ButtonClick(4)
    elif (2 in p1) and (3 in p1) or (4 in p1) and (7 in p1) or (5 in p1) and (9 in p1):
        ButtonClick(1)
    else:
        ButtonClick(EmptyCells[RandIndex])


root=mainloop()


#This is how the autoplay() should be without if statement so the game works fine:
def AutoPlay():
    global p1
    global p2
    EmptyCells=[]
    for cell in range(9):
        if (not((cell+1 in p1) or (cell+1 in p2))):
            EmptyCells.append(cell+1)
    RandIndex=randint(0,len(EmptyCells)-1)
    ButtonClick(EmptyCells[RandIndex])
```

Comment: Apparently your "AI" does click, but it clicks on a non-Empty cell so you can't actually see the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I described in my comment the computer is able to "click" into non-empty squares. To prevent that, you can just check if the square the computer wants to click in is empty:

```
if ((1 in p1) and (2 in p1) or (6 in p1) and (9 in p1) or (5 in p1) and (7 in p1)) and 3 in EmptyCells:
    ButtonClick(3)
```

This is really janky, but since you are just starting out, this will be the easiest to understand.

Comment: the problem, it still get stuck after a round or two :/

Comment: Have you added the EmptyCells check to every click with the corresponding button?

Comment: Your solution worked ty so much i just found an error in my code later ty anyways